Right speaker still not working. I've checked a number of solutions that have been suggested, that I have found posted on th internet
Here's my setup.
   OS: Ubuntu Studio 24.10 (Oracular Oriole)
   KDE Plasma version: 6.1.5
   KDE Frameworks version: 6.6.0
   Qt version: 6.6.2
   Kernel version: 6.11.0-9-generic
   Graphics platform: X11
   Processors: 8 × 11th Gen Intel Core i7-1165G7 @ 2.80GHz
   RAM: 15.3 GiB
   Graphics processor: Mesa Intel Xe graphics
   Moodel: HP Spectre x360 Convertible 13-aw2xxx
The system it seems, defaults to PipeWire 1.2.4 as the audio driver software. I've checked the pipewire GUI configs and they look fine.

Test is being done via the KDE GUI Menu, Settings, System settings, Sound, 'Playback device - Speaker' Test

Two channels (Left & Right) are shown both at = 130%
Popup (Click on any speaker to test sound)
Left Speaker - Test works fine -
Right Speaker - Test = No sound at all -
Fresh install, All updates downloaded and installed.
Bluetooth headphones work on both left and right channels.
Regular phono jack, headphones, plugged into the headphone audio phono socket work fine - Test - as above, indicates both channels are working quite interdependently and individually as separate stereo channels.

I should also point out that the speaker is set to 'Play HiFi quality Music' Not 'Pro Audio'. When I set it to Pro Audio - Nothing works.

I feel this is a bug in the Oracular Oriole OS?

Just to point, both speakers are working just fine with Windows and earlier versions of Ubuntu-Studio. So this is not a hardware issue.

It's got to to be somewhere between the hardware and the speaker.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I just wanted to let you know that bugs are off topic here. Does the right speaker work if you boot from the live Ubuntu installation USB using the Try Ubuntu option?
